# PFQuery on Array for item starts with String

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I have an array of search keywords as a field in a custom object and i wanna make a search when user just enter 2 or 3 characters of any of the array items for 
example

```
["cafe" , "food" , "eat"]
["car" , "Gas"]
```

if user entered `caf` it should return the object contains this search keyword

```
[query whereKey:@"keywords" greaterThan:keyword];
```

returns not relevant data it returns the 2 rows of `car and cafe` !

I also tried equalTo

```
[query whereKey:@"keywords" equalTo:keyword];
```

but to get the row back i should enter the whole word

any ideas what i should query on?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but if I understand it correctly, can't you just get the array of all the words and compare it locally?
Like this: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/auto-complete-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

Comment: i wanna make a life search and i have a lot of data 
every item have some search keywords and i wanna get results if user entered part of the search keyword 
for example i have 3 items 
objectId: x keywords["cafe" , "food"]
objectId: y keywords["cafe" , "food"]
objectId: z keywords["car" , "Gas"]
when i search for "caf" it should return the (x and y) only

Comment: you shouldn't be performing queries for this circumstance, even though you technically can, for one, its over-the-air so a user without internet connection won't be able to use this service. 2) it will utilize an API request overtime you perform it, which accumulates exponentially quicker with searches as opposed to normal situations. You don't want that. Save an array locally and just filter through it with NSPredicate

Comment: i know about the requests for sure. it's a customer requirement :/
. i now need to know the query that i can do this functionality with.